# Preferred way of creating links with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around backbone.js but I'm finding it hard due to the lack of (IMO) good examples.

First of all, what is the best way of getting a link to an object.
If I want to get the edit url of an `Album` model I could do `album.url() + '/edit'`, is this really the best way?

Also, I'm trying to make my application work 100% without javascript so I don't want my URLs/links to say `/albums/#1/edit`, I want it to be `/albums/1/edit` and override this in JS.

I'm thinking I create normal URLs and use `jQuery.live` to call `router.navigate` in backbone.js
I never got this to work however, when I call `router.navigate('/albums/2', true)` the URL changes but my show action is never called. If I refresh it's called so the route is matched.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The basic answer, which is kind of frustrating, is "there is no preferred way!". Backbone.js doesn't tell you how to set up links, you can do it any way you like. I found this flexibility just as annoying as you do, at least at first.

So here's the way I'm approaching this on [my current project](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/gapvis), with the (big) caveat that this is just one of many ways to do things in Backbone:

- For the most part, I don't use actual links. There's no explicit reason not to, but it means you have to keep track of a bunch of URL strings that have to be consistent. I would rather stick all the URL formatting in my routers and not deal with it elsewhere.
- To open a new "top-level" view, like an editing screen, I set something that fires an event. In the application I'm currently working on, I have a global State model, and to open a new view I call `state.set({ topview: MyTopView })`. This causes the `state` object to trigger `change:topview`.
- Any piece of the UI that needs to change when the top-level view changes has an update method bound to `change:topview`. When the event fires, they look at `state.get('topview')` and update as necessary.
- I treat my routers as only marginally specialized parts of the UI - they're essentially views that render in the browser address bar, rather than the window. Like other views, they update the `state` object on UI events (i.e. a new URL), and like other views, they listen to the `state` object for changes that cause them to update. The logic that the editing screen has the URL `albums/<albumid>/edit` is fully encapsulated in the router, and I don't refer to it anywhere else.

This works well for me, but it adds an entirely new pattern, the global State object, to the Backbone structure, so I can hardly call this the "preferred" approach.

**Update:** Also note that `.url()`, in the Backbone idiom, refers to the model's URL in the *back-end API*, not the front-end URL (it's not like Django's `get_absolute_url`). There is no method in the default Backbone setup that gives you a user-facing URL for your model - you'd have to write this yourself.

Comment: Great post! Any idea why `navigate` doesn't call my router?

Comment: I'd have to see more code - passing `true` to navigate should call the function associated with the route, so either your route isn't recognized as matching a route pattern, or the function isn't doing what you expect...

Comment: Ah, the navigate-url must be an exact match to the route meaning I had to remove the inital /

Answer (score 7):

> Also, I'm trying to make my application work 100% without javascript; so I don't want my URLs/links to say `/albums/#1/edit`, I want it to be `/albums/1/edit` and override this in JS.

you can do exactly this w/ pushState. just enable it in your Backbone.history.start call:

`Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`

this tells Backbone to use the HTML5 History API (a.k.a. "PushState"), which uses full URLs exactly like you're wanting.

read up on the history api here: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/history.html

and I wrote up a 2 part series on using pushstate w/ the second part focusing on progressive enhancement in backbone, to do what you're needing:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/

and

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/

hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm using `router.navigate` now, it's working nicely except when the user want to go back in the history, backbone then calls all previous actions in the controller. Filed a bug. Thanks for the info though!