# Why router.navigate() in Backbone.js do not load required view?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm new in BackboneJS, RequireJS, JQuery apps development. I want to change the current view using `router.navigate()`. This is the router configuration:

```
 define([

    //Libraries to load
    "jquery",
    "underscore", 
    "backbone",
    "mustache",

    //Views to load
    "../views/Main",
    "../views/Login",
    "../views/Dashboard",
    "../views/Empty"

], function ($, _, Backbone, Mustache, MainView, LoginView, DashboardView, HomeView) {

    //All of the dependencies in the array above become parameters of the function to be managed
    'use strict';

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // Default
            '*actions': 'defaultAction'
        },
        loadView: function(view){
            this.view && (this.view.close ? this.view.close() : this.view.remove());
            this.view = view;
            this.view.render();
        }
    });

    var initialize = function(){
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (actions) {
            switch (actions){
                case "login": this.loadView(new LoginView()); break;
                case "home": this.loadView(new HomeView()); break;
            } 
        });

        // Extend the View class to include a navigation method goTo (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755344/using-the-backbone-js-router-to-navigate-through-views-modularized-with-require)
        Backbone.View.prototype.goTo = function (loc) {
            app_router.navigate(loc, true);
        };
        Backbone.Model.prototype.goTo = function (loc) {
            app_router.navigate(loc, true);
        };
        Backbone.history.start();
    };



    return  {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

In the Backbonejs View I use the following code to change/load views:

```
self.goTo("home");
```

But only change the hashtag in the URL. For example: `#login` change to `#home`, but not load the view. I have to reload page with the URL `#home` to load the home view.

NOTE: `Backbone.history.navigate("viewname", { trigger: true });` produce the same result. Change the URL but not route to view.

---

My router code with applied:

```
routes: {
        'login': 'renderLogin',
        'home': 'renderHome',
        // Default
        '*actions': 'renderDefault'
    },
    renderDefault: function(){
        this.view = new MainView();
        this.view.render();
    },
    renderLogin: function(){
        this.view = new LoginView();
        this.view.render();
    },
    renderHome: function(){
        this.view = new HomeView();
        this.view.render();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably showing on your console a message that 'defaultAction' does not exist, or its undefined.

When you declare your routes, you need to follow the convention of backoneJS like this:

```
routes: {
      //Default
     '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    },
```

The string before ':' it's what backbone will 'see' or 'listening' in browser url.

If the url 'match' with that string.

The strign after ':' will be the function name that backbone will call when '*actions' be on your url.

In your case you have no funcion called "defaultAction". That's is the problem.

Now to try to improve your code, i believe that you could create an function to every view that you want. It allows you to navigate and render the correct view according with you url.

Example:

```
routes{
    'index':'renderIndex'
    'home' : 'renderHome'
},

renderIndex: function(view){
     //render your Indexview
    },

renderHome: function(view){
     //render your Homeview
    }
```

This way you can navigate through your application using urls:

youapp.com/#home (will render the home view)
youapp.com/#index (will render the index view)

Comment: Thanks, @rcarvalho. I modified my router and applied the suggested changes. Now my app redirects all URL requested and is not necesary and no need to manually refresh the view.