# How to render only required files in backbone router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, require

- I have written a backbone router and it's working fine.
- For the first time when it's load, all the files which given in router define method are getting called.
- But I want only the specific page load files to get loaded, whether it is first time or second time...
- If I removed the rest of view files that not to be loaded, how do I create a instances for other views and where I have to define them.

Is there a way to solve this. Please help.

This is how the router is coded:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'landingView',
    'pdpView'

], function($, _, Backbone,LandingView, PdpView) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'landing': 'landingView',
            'pdp': 'pdp',
            '*actions': 'default'
        }

    });

    var initialize = function(){
        var a_router = new AppRouter;

        a_router.on('route:landing', function(){
            var landingView = new LandingView();
            landingView.render();
        });

        a_router.on('route:pdp', function(){
            var pdpView = new PdpView();
            pdpView.render();
        });

        a_router.on('route:default', function(){
            var landingView = new LandingView();
            landingView.render();
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Comment: Erik Ringsmuth wrote [requirejs-router](https://github.com/erikringsmuth/requirejs-router) that lazy loads views.  [Executive summary in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21890967/3585500).

Comment: @ourmandave: Thank u very much helped a lot, and my issue is solved